# How are papers on NIPS Proceedings licensed?

Tags: license

I can see that there is a copyright claim on the [NIPS Proceedings webpage](https://papers.nips.cc/) for the years 1987 to 2017 but I haven't been able to find under what license the papers are copyrighted. How can I see that?

In particular, I'm looking for the license of the images in the paper "[ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks)."

Answer (score 1):

The proceedings of NIPS is presently published by Curran Associates (2005–present) under the name Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems. So, it follows the copyright and license as per Curran Associates regulations.

Please see the link here: [[Curran Associates]](http://www.proceedings.com/)

Comment: Can you comment in layman's words what this implies for usage? Is this similar to a CC license?